# Read XML File in Qt

Tags: xml, qt, parsing

I would like to read the following XML file in Qt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Math>
   <Equation>
      <eq1>
         <value1>5</value1>
         <value2>3</value2>
      </eq1>
      <eq2>
         <value1>5</value1>
         <value2>3</value2>
      </eq2>
   </Equation>
   <Variables>
      <var1>
        <val1>
           <number1>1.5</number1>
           <number2>0.2</number2>
        </val1>
        <val2>
           <number1>1.5</number1>
           <number2>0.2</number2>
        </val2>
      </var1>
      <var2>
        <val1>
          <number1>2.5</number1>
          <number2>1.2</number2>
        </val1>
        <val2>
          <number1>2.5</number1>
          <number2>1.2</number2>
        </val2>
      </var2>
   </Variables>
</Math>
```

I tried it like this:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"),
    QDir::currentPath(), tr("*.xml"));
    QFile inFile(fileName);

    if (!inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
    }

    QXmlStreamReader xmlReader(&inFile);

    while (xmlReader.readNextStartElement())
    {
        if (xmlReader.name() == "Equation")
        {
            while (xmlReader.readNextStartElement())        // eq(n)
            {
                while (xmlReader.readNextStartElement())    // value(n)
                {
                    if (xmlReader.name() == "value1")
                    {
                        ui.textEdit->append(xmlReader.readElementText());
                    }

                    if (xmlReader.name() == "value2")
                    {
                        ui.textEdit->append(xmlReader.readElementText());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (xmlReader.name() == "Variables")
        {
            while (xmlReader.readNextStartElement())        // var(n)
            {
                while (xmlReader.readNextStartElement())    // val(n)
                {
                    while (xmlReader.readNextStartElement())// num(n)
                    {
                        if (xmlReader.name() == "number1")
                        {
                            ui.textEdit->append(xmlReader.readElementText());
                        }

                        if (xmlReader.name() == "number2")
                        {
                            ui.textEdit->append(xmlReader.readElementText());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This outputs:

```
5
3
5
3
1.5
0.2
```

But I expect the output to be:

```
5
3
5
3
1.5
0.2
1.5
0.2
2.5
1.2
```

What I am doing wrong? Is there a simpler solution for it?
I think this method is really awkward.

I just want to save all values in vectors.

For example vector "Equation" should contain 2 vectors ("eq1","eq2") each containg the values "val1" and "val2".

Comment: I can suggest using the Qt XML module with the QDomDocument main class. for small XML files it is far better and easier to use.

Comment: Have you considered adding debug prints to each branch, so you would know what actually happens in your code? `qDebug() << __FILE__ << __LINE__ << __FUNCTION__;` is easy to copy-paste and allows you to track what happens. Or, try using the debugger.

Comment: @Xander The [documentation for Qt XML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxml-module.html) explicitly tells you to use QXmlStreamReader/Writer instead. Qt XML is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the use of multiple nested loops in which you call the same method: `xmlReader.readNextStartElement()`. The most nested loop you get into skips through the rest of the file not giving any chance to the outer loops. In fact, the `Equation` tag in your example is only processed correctly because there's just one such tag; if there were two or more, you'd only have the first one parsed.

Your solution can be changed like the following:

```
QString previousElement;
while(!xmlReader.atEnd())
{
    xmlReader.readNext();

    if (!xmlReader.isStartElement()) {
        continue;
    }

    QString text = xmlReader.name().toString();
    if ( (text == QStringLiteral("value1")) ||
         (text == QStringLiteral("value2")) ||
         (text == QStringLiteral("number1")) ||
         (text == QStringLiteral("number2")) )
    {
        ui->textEdit->append(xmlReader.readElementText());
    }
}

if (xmlReader.hasError()) {
    ui->textEdit->setText(QStringLiteral("Error parsing XML: ") + xmlReader.errorString());
}
```