# How to read from xml file correctly in Qt/C++

Tags: c++, xml, qt5

I have such xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#">
  <metadata
     id="metadata1030">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
</svg>
```

And this code

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSvg>
#include <iostream>
#include <QTextStream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QFile file("example.svg");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    QXmlStreamReader reader(&file);
    while(!reader.atEnd())
    {
        auto token = reader.readNextStartElement();
        qDebug()<<reader.name();

    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Gives me the next output:

```
"svg"
"metadata"
"RDF"
```

But I want to take access to all headers, How do I can take the next output?

```
"svg"
"metadata"
"RDF"
"Work"
"format"
"type"
```

It is advisable not to change the xml file, but to change the code.

Comment: Since you are working with Scalable Vector Graphics i.e. SVG more likely you don't need to parse XML with your own. [Check Manual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsvg-index.html) it contains examples for rendering and generation. Or you are interested how XML stream (pull) parser is working ?

Comment: No, I don't need to work with graphics, I need to parse an xml file.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852303/read-xml-file-in-qt

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the namespaces. The ones that were declared are not showing. Try turning off reader.namespaceProcessing =false;   also, try reader.qualifiedName() to see whether that works though you probably only want the local names.

Comment: T33C, thank you, reader.setNamespaceProcessing(false); worked for me